# Find BST with daylight savings in ruby

Tags: ruby, timezone

I have ruby scripts for running automated tests. I'm trying to find out the current time in London and setting my timezone environmental variable to 'London'(`ENV['TZ']='London'`). It still outputs the current time as `UTC(BST-1)`. Is there a way to get the British Summer Time accurately?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [TZInfo Gem](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo)

```
require 'tzinfo'
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('Europe/London')
puts "The current time in London is #{tz.now}"
```